# How to change group of CSS items in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want to change group of CSS items in jqGrid. [Documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#setting-css-classes) is saying

> Of course if we want to change not only one CSS item from a group, but two or more we can use jQuery extend to do this:

```
var my_col_definition  = {
  icon_move : 'ui-icon-arrow-1',
  icon_menu : "ui-icon-pencil"
}
$.extend( $.jgrid.styleUI.jQueryUI.colmenu , my_col_definition );
```

And this is working partially. But I want to override all icons in my `Bootstrap` with next code:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.styleUI.Bootstrap, {
  common: {
    icon_base: "fa"
  },
  inlinedit: {
    icon_edit_nav: "fa-edit"
  },
  navigator: {
    icon_edit_nav: "fa-edit"
  },
  // ...
});
```

and my grid stops working and does not respond to any commands. There are no errors in console.

Do anybody know how to fix the problem in an elegant way and do not override every group separately?

Answer (score 0):

It is unknown which versions of Guriddo jqGrid and Bootstrap are used.
I see you try to use the fontAwesome.

With the last release you can use fontAwesome with ths following settings:

```
<script>
    $.jgrid.defaults.styleUI = 'Bootstrap4';
    $.jgrid.defaults.iconSet = "fontAwesome";
</script>
```

And point to the needed css files as described in [this documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/#using-bootstrap-v4-css-framework)

You can change the icons the way you do in your code without problems - I have tested this and it works.

In any case, please prepare a simple demo which reproduces the problem, so that we can look into it.